# How can I set a logging level with Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The default logger prints a lot of mostly useless info:
    app.use(express.logger());

Is there a way to set a level for the express logger?

Comment: The express logger is just a simple logger for logging requests in development, for a more proper logger I'd sugges using [Winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Since Express 4](http://expressjs.com/guide/migrating-4.html#core-changes), you should use [Morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan).

```
npm install morgan
```

and

```
var morgan = require('morgan');
app.use(morgan('tiny'));
```